# Bash scripting: Crossplatform check is python package installed in the system?

Tags: linux, unix, bash

For example I want to check does py-sqlite3 available..? One of the methods would to call that command with some minimum python script and catch error?

I want to make check for any linux distro and unix system (at least bsd)

What could be the best way to achieve this?

P.s. Please provide example of shell scripting error catching, because I'm not so advanced in shell scripting

Comment: probably better to ask stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found existing answers incomplete and lacking good enough examples. Here is the solution I have settled on:

```
# an example checking if the pandas package is installed
if python -c 'import pkgutil; exit(not pkgutil.find_loader("pandas"))'; then
    echo 'pandas found'
else
    echo 'pandas not found'
fi
```

A Github gist of this example can be found here:
https://gist.github.com/shaypal5/d505af9953cd86f59c750fa600ee4ba6

Answer (score 3):

In bash:

```
$ python -c 'import sqlite3' 2>/dev/null && echo "python sqlite3 modules install" || echo "python sqlite3 modules not install"
python sqlite3 modules install

$ python -c 'import sqlite3' 2>/dev/null && echo "python sqlite3 modules install" || echo "python sqlite3 modules not install"
python sqlite3 modules not install
```

Answer (score 2):

```
package_exist(){
    package=$1
    if pip freeze | grep $package=; then
        echo "$package found"
    else
        echo "$package not found"
    fi
}
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
package_exist package_name
```

Comment: The question makes no mention of pip being used to install packages.

Answer (score 1):

This would be easy to do with Python.

```
import sys

try:
    import sqlite3
except ImportError:
    sys.exit(1)
else:
    sys.exit(0)
```

Exits with `return code 0` if it can import it, or `return code 1` if it cannot.

Andrew

Comment: if this would be launched in another shell script, how can I detect return code with bash script?

Comment: bash has special variable that stores return code; try echo $? after command, and if it's 0 it was ok, if it was greater than 0 something went wrong.